# Adobe Flex Progress Bar for LoadStyleDeclarations

Tags: apache-flex, progress-bar, styles

I'm loading a rather large swf as style with the following command:

```
StyleManager.loadStyleDeclarations("assets/modules/"style.swf",true,false,ApplicationDomain.currentDomain);
```

The style is loaded fine but now I would like to add a progress bar to it, but I do not know how to do so. I am rather new to Flex and found only examples referring to HTML service calls.

Thank You for Your Help. It would be great to receive a small code example.

Answer (score 1):

```
var dispatcher:IEventDispatcher = StyleManager.loadStyleDeclarations(
        "assets/modules/style.swf",true,false,ApplicationDomain.currentDomain);

dispatcher.addEventListener(StyleEvent.PROGRESS, onProgress);
dispatcher.addEventListener(StyleEvent.COMPLETE, onComplete);
dispatcher.addEventListener(StyleEvent.ERROR, onError);

private function onProgress(e:StyleEvent):void
{
    //update progress bar here
    trace(Math.floor(100 * e.bytesLoaded/e.bytesTotal) + "% loaded");
}
private function onComplete(e:StyleEvent):void
{
    trace("Style loaded");
}
private function onError(e:StyleEvent):void
{
    trace("Error loading style");
}
```

Comment: Hi, I am creating an app which imports data into a sqlite db. I need to show a progress bar / "Please Wait" spinner animation so that the user waits till the operation completes. How can this code be modified for this situation? Thanks.